# How can I stop saving credentials in windows credential manager?

Tags: windows, git, credentials, credential-manager, git-credential-manager

**Why is windows credential saving my git password without my knowledge ?**

I am saving my config file in text format ( for portability reasons) by using the below command. It works fine even after I deleted the git credential from the windows credential manager.

```
git config  credential.helper store
```

After some time of my work, Windows credentials may contain/save my credentials without my concern.  **How to block windows credentials to access my portable git credentials ?**

*As per my understanding:*

```
## credential will save in Credential Manager
git config --global credential.helper wincred

## Credential will take from config file ( as we definded ) 
git config  credential.helper store
```

Please suggest any ideas or suggestions

**Note:**

*I am using GitHub portable so, I can finish code anywhere. The GitHub helper popup will ask for GitHub credentials during the push. But I can close, still pull/push works fine for me.*

Please ignore if I made any grammar mistakes

Comment: What's the value of `git config --get credential.helper` in the repository where it works unexpectedly?

Comment: Did you try to use `ssh`?

Comment: @ElpieKay value of git config credential.helper is store